# how to use mssql with electron.js in such way that we don't need to install every time on each computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2008, electron

i am trying to create a desktop app with mssql and electron.js i want to build it in such way that we don't need to install mssql every time and connect it with electron application on each computer. How can i do that ?

Comment: By using a single host in your domain that *all* the computers connect to, rather than a local instance. Of course, if your app is designed to be using a local instance, then that'll require a significant redesign of your database.

Comment: yeah i am using local host instance. Is their any way i export the database and procedures so that i just call it in electron app?